# Converting char to integer using C

Tags: c, string

I need to create a program that change only a letter to upper or lower case, without the use of functions.

This program is via command line. I was trying to test the argument, comparing argv[1] with the ASCII table, but before that, I can't convert it to integer using strtoul. It always returns 0. The code snippet is like that:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv){

    char *val;
    char charac;

charac = (char) strtoul (argv[1], &val, 10);

/////charac returns zero here, but it needs to return the ASCII integer value////

if ((charac < 'A') || (charac > 'Z' && charac < 'a') || (charac > 'z'))
    {
      printf ("Invalid character!!\n", charac);
    }
}
```

How could I perform this convertion?

Comment: Did you read `strtoul()`'s documentation?

Comment: The title is "converting char to integer" but the first line talks about changing letter case. I don't see how the two are related. What is the question?

Comment: Yes, i read the strtoul doc and i need to use it to convert.

Comment: And, yes. I only need to change a letter case, but using only a function and to test any possibility when the user types in the command line

Answer (score 0):

```
charac = argv[1][0];
if ((charac >= 'A') && (charac <= 'Z'))
    printf("Lowercased: %c\n", charac - 'A' + 'a');
else if ((charac >= 'a') && (charac <= 'z'))
    printf("Uppercased: %c\n", charac - 'a' + 'A');
else
    print ("Invalid character: %c\n", charac);
```

Comment: sorry, but i need to test before doing that if the argument is valid, i.e., a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Taken for [here](http://www.findsourcecode.com/c-programming/convert-character-from-lowercase-to-uppercase/) but modified a lot, including an extra function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char lower_to_upper(char ch1)
{
      char ch2;

      if(ch1 >= 'a' && ch1 <= 'z'){
            ch2 = ('A' + ch1 - 'a');
            return ch2;
      }
      else{
            ch2 = ch1;
            return ch2;
      }
}

char upper_to_lower (char ch1)
{
      char ch2;

      if(ch1 >= 'A' && ch1 <= 'Z'){
            ch2 = ('a' + ch1 - 'A');
            return ch2;
      }
      else{
            ch2 = ch1;
            return ch2;
      }
}


int main()
{
      char charac, different_case;

      printf("Please input a character: ");
      scanf("%c", &charac);

      if (charac >= 'a' && charac <= 'z')
          different_case = lower_to_upper (charac);
      else if (charac >= 'A' && charac <='Z')
          different_case = upper_to_lower (charac);

      printf("The different case equivalent is: %c\n", different_case);
      return 0;
}
```

The algorithm is explained nicely on the link mentioned.

Example output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I need to test my program so that it can verify if the typed letter is indeed a letter or not. that's why i'm trying to use the strtoul. If i type a number or a simbol using your program, what would be the answer??

Comment: With stroul you do may verify that it's a digit, but no more. BTW, you claimed than no extra func should be used :) if it's not  strict condition, try isalpha, isupper, toupper, islower, tolower.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation. Function `foo()` takes a word (an character array in fact) as an argument and performs upper case->lower case or lower case ->upper case conversion where necessary.

```
char *foo(char *word){
    char *tmp = word; /* For the new string */
    char *ptr = word; /* To save the poiner */

    for(; *ptr; ++ptr, ++tmp) {
        if (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z')
        /* char is lower case */
            *tmp = (*ptr) - 32;
        else if (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z')
        /* char is upper case */
            *tmp = (*ptr) + 32;
        else
            *tmp = *ptr;
    }
    return word;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[]="This is a test LiNe FOR You";
    char *buf;

    printf("%s\n",foo(strtok(line," ")));

    while(buf=strtok(NULL," "))
        printf("%s\n",foo(buf));

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output of the code above.. `main()` includes a `strtok()` step, which you can ignore for your question

```
$ ./lower_upper
tHIS
IS
A
TEST
lInE
for
yOU
```